# Split Function in c# not working properly

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string Var = ",A,,,B,,C";
    string[] members = Var.Split(',');
    foreach (string member in members)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(member);
    }
    Console.WriteLine(members.Length);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The **output** of the above code is

```
A


B

C
7
```

the `7 is length of the array` , but my question is that when i passed `','`
 in parameters of split function.

so why it  takes initial ',' as a space . and why it takes 2 out of 3 ',' as space after A . and why it takes 1 out of 2 ',' as space after B ?

Comment: Do your homework and read the documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: because Split() consider there is a 'space' between ,,

Comment: Check the length of the "spaces" - I think you will find that Split is returning an empty string - which is exactly what precedes the first comma & is between the others. Change the WriteLine in your loop to this _"Console.WriteLine(">" + member + "< " + member.Length + " " + (member==null));"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for you question is, this is not space but this is empty string

`string` can be empty and you are seeing this as space.

`,,` <- after `,` we have nothing, so split method adds empty string.

If you want to remove this, you have to put after `','` `StringSplitOptions`

`Var.Split(new char [] {','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Split does not add null - it adds an empty string.

Comment: String.Empty is NOT the same as null. Run OPs code with this WriteLine  _"Console.WriteLine(">" + member + "< " + member.Length + " " + (member==null) + " " + (member==String.Empty));"_

Comment: @PaulF You are true again. I has just remembered string.IsNullOrEmpty

Comment: @faizan: You should mark this answer as correct now it has been edited - as it adds the information about the split options letting you choose not to get empty entries.

Comment: @PaulF i just wanted to add it before you wrote. Thanks 3x :)

Answer (score 0):

/*For this Question only the function "split()" counts. we can give any special character to split the array elements.
Note: It is not applicable for special characters like single quotations and double quotations*/

```
        string Var = "-%%A-,,$$,-B-@@%-C";
        string[] members = Var.Split('-',',','@','$','%');
        foreach (string member in members)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(member);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(members.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

The Image shows the output console screen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aArY5.png

Answer (score -1):

because you have a space before first ',' and because there is only one place holder between B and C?